# How to actually delete(modify) nodes from XML file in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Good day to all, I've been having this problem for two days now and I still have not got the correct solution to this even in this site so I am very hoping that someone out there can provide me some answers. Thanks in advance!

so here's my problem, I've been trying to delete a node from an external XML file from a different package, it loads successfully by the way. Now, I want to delete node at index[x] then I tried printing the data in the xml file again, the node i wanted to remove is gone...BUT...when I open the file in the directory, the node is still there, I tried refreshing the file, still it's there...please help me, here is my code.

> Actionscript code

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);             
   var bookList: XML =  new XML();

function loadXML(e:Event):void{
   bookList =  new XML(e.target.data);
    delete bookList.book[3];
tlabel.text = bookList.book; //test lable coz trace wont work
}

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("xmldata/data.xml"));  //Loading XML data
```

> XML Code

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer 123</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
          <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
          society in England, the young survivors lay the 
          foundation for a new society.</description>
       </book>  
</catalog>
```

Comment: Are you working in Adobe AIR or Flex or Flash?

Comment: I am working with flex sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the loaded xml data inside your application not the actual XML file. You need to save the altered xml in the location to view the changes.

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);             
   var bookList: XML =  new XML();

function loadXML(e:Event):void{
   bookList =  new XML(e.target.data);
    delete bookList.book[3];
tlabel.text = bookList.book; //test lable coz trace wont work

// code to save your xml
var uploader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var data:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
data.xml = bookList.toXMLString();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://locahost/saveXML.php");
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.data = data;
uploader.load(req);

}

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("xmldata/data.xml"));  //Loading XML data
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
file_put_contents('path/to/file', $_POST['data']);
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: oh, thank you for that insight, i am kind of relieved to know that...uhm, i guess now, my question redirects to how do i save the altered file? :D

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377830/i-need-to-save-xml-from-flex-to-file-on-server-with-php-which-php-script)

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply, thanks you for this...however, I am trying to do this in flex, and I dont have any idea on how to do the php code that u gave into actionscript3/flex, again, I humbly ask you again for another solution/code...thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You cannot save files using Flex since Flash Player doesn't have access to user's system. But you can use the FileReference class’s new save() method in Flash Player 10 to save files to a user’s hard drive. using this method will prompt the save dialogue and you need to select the location where you want to save the file. Check the [link](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/25/saving-files-locally-using-the-filereference-classs-save-method-in-flash-player-10/).

Comment: I figured it out, thank you for all the inputs!
All i did was create a filestream but it did not work at first because my project runs with flash player(ergo web-based or in a browser), but when I changed it to a Desktop application(plays using air player), the filestream now works and i can directly access local directory and save the file changes. Thank you so much everyone!